# "Out of Memory" error using Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst

I get an "Out of memory" error when running a closest facility analysis on a fairly large public transport network dataset using network analyst ArcGIS 10.2, even when the process is only utilizing about 3.1gb out of my 8gb memory computer.

Any idea on why this error comes up, and what can be done to fix this?

Comment: 32-bit applications can't generally use even 3.1Gb, so that total is likely for active all applications.  If you use a memory monitor on the Desktop application, you'll likely see it nax out at ~1.4Gb. There may be steps you can take in Windows to get a bit more RAM available, but once the heap is exhausted, you've hit the platform limit.

Answer (score 2):

try using the 64 bit background processing http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//002100000040000000

Otherwise chunk the data.